# Why the data type in last columns is str instead of float?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

All the data fomr column B to column K are numbers stored as text in excel file.
[image]

I have uploaded the excel file in dropbox as a sample to test with.
[sample data text](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwltvuaq36mfy0p/tsm.xlsx?dl=0)

Download it and save in `/tmp/tsm.xlsx`.

[tsm.xlsx for testing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwltvuaq36mfy0p/tsm.xlsx?dl=0)

I find that data type in the last cloumn K  is str,column from B till J are all in numbers type after reading it into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
sexcel = '/tmp/tsm.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(sexcel,sheet_name='ratios_annual')
row_num = len(df)
for id in range(row_num):
    print('the data type in last column--K is',type(df.iloc[id,-1]))
    print('the data type in  column--J is',type(df.iloc[id,-2]))

the data type in last column--K is <class 'str'>
the data type in  column--J is <class 'numpy.float64'>
the data type in last column--K is <class 'str'>
the data type in  column--J is <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

It's obvious that from column B till column K are all `number stored as text` when opening it in excel.Why the types differ when i read it into a dataframe?
Please download the sample data and have a check.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with `openpyxl==3.1.1` and `pandas==1.5.3`

Can you include the packages you have installed in your question (`pip list`)?

Pandas have a few excel engines it can use to read files ("xlrd", "openpyxl", "odf", "pyxlsb"). This behaviour might be exclusive to one of them.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L378

Comment: I have already upgraded into newer higher version,and the issue gone,how can i find out the previous lower version?

Comment: If your env installation is in a cloud synced folder, you can check the previous `openpyxl` version in the site-packages folder: `<python or virtual environment path>/lib/python<version>/site-packages/openpyxl-<version>.dist-info`

Otherwise, you can try to remember when you installed `openpyxl` last and check the latest release at the time:
https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/#history

Ultimatelly, you can try all previous versions of `openpyxl`. Writing a bash script for this wouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded the file via Dropbox and loaded it in my `pandas` environment that has the following versions (installed from `conda-forge`):

```yaml
- pandas=1.5.3
- openpyxl=3.1.0
```

The code snippet in the original question executes correctly, all data columns are identified as `floats`. Please check your versions of `pandas` and `openpyxl` and upgrade, if it's feasible:

```py
from pandas import __version__
print(__version__) # 1.5.3

from openpyxl import __version__
print(__version__) # 3.1.0
```

Comment: It is funny to solve my issue just only by upgrading pandas to version1.5.3 and openpyxl to version3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to explicitly convert that column into float? By default, Pandas tries to correctly infer data types, but it might get it wrong if the data is not perfect (e.g. column has a character somewhere, etc.). Try converting that column to float and it might lead you to where the issue is.

```
df["2012"] = df["2012"].astype(float)
```

Comment: Why other column were converted without error?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some bad values in your column. To find them, use:

```
out = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['2012'], errors='coerce').isna(), '2012']
print(out)
```

Comment: I can't find bad values with your code,please try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code below;

```
import pandas as pd

file = f"my_excel.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file, dtype='object')
cols = ['2021', '2020', '2019']

for i in cols:
    df[i] = df[i].astype(float) # that could be "int" as well

df.info()
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading this into a dataframe as a CSV file worked for me.  After downloading the .xslx file, export this as CSV, and load into pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("tsm.csv")
```